# Execute many sed commands in a row

Tags: regex, bash, sed, terminal

Terminal novice here. I have a long text file with many different strings. I need to change all of them to short codes, like so:

`string 1` should change to `ABC`
`string 2` should change to `LMN`
`string 3` should change to `XYZ`

And so on. I know how to change one of these at a time with a basic `sed` command. And I understand that I can pipe one `sed` command to another. However, I have about 1000 string changes needed. Surely there's a better way to do this than 1000 pipes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `sed` command too?

Comment: How do you have the data stored on what strings need to be change to what?  Is there a choice of formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although most people only use sed for 'one-liners', sed is a (limited purpose) scripting language and can be used for more complex stuff. As such, it lets you take your sed commands as input from a file. What you want to do is create a file with one sed command per line, like so:

```
s/string 1/ABC/g
s/string 2/LMN/g
s/string 3/XYZ/g
```

and then save that to a file, say 'shortCodes.sed'

Then, on the command-line, you say

> sed -f shortCodes.sed < inputfile > outputfile

NOTE: the `/g` at the end of the pattern match specifies a 'global' replace: so that if the same string appears more than once in a line, it will be replaced each time - you may or may not want this, depending on your application.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use multiple `s` commands with sed:

```
sed -e 's|string 1|ABC|' -e 's|string 2|LMN|' -e 's|string 3|XYZ|' your_file
```

Or separate with semicolons:

```
sed -e 's|string 1|ABC|; s|string 2|LMN|; s|string 3|XYZ|' your_file
```

Comment: Or write sed commands to a file and use option `-f script-file`.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes you're correct. I considered file input however I'm not sure how the OP would want to have the values stored. There may be an easier solution than manually typing every command depending on his data.

Comment: @konsolebox @Cyrus I had the codes build in a spreadsheet and could automate all the repetitive typing of pipes etc., but pasting such long commands (thousands of characters) into Terminal makes it grind to a halt in my experience. So the first answer works better for me. Very helpful to learn how to group `sed` commands, though - thank you!